# How to store variables between views in backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

In backbone.js, I have many views which are different pages.
As I am going from page to page, this is a wizard, so there must be a variable (class instance) to store the data from page to page. How and where can I store this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a model that represents the object that the wizard is setting up.  Pass that model to each of the views.  Now each view is showing a different aspect of the same model.

```
var Thing = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Page1 = Backbone.View.extend({});
var Page2 = Backbone.View.extend({});

var myThing = new Thing();
var myPage1 = new Page1({model: myThing});
var myPage2 = new Page2({model: myThing});
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually have a *parent* view which handles initialisation of "child" views. With this approach, you can create a property on *parent* view and make it available to *child* views.

Another way to do it would be to pass data from one wizard page to another via custom events.